# Использование типа из библиотеки для обьявления, без подключения этой библиотеки. С++

Tags: c++

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы не подключать библиотеку в заговолочном файле, если я хочу только обьявить метод или оператор. А вот уже в `.cpp` все подключить и уже описать метод или перегрузку оператора ?

```
// -----------Test.h-------------
    #ifdnef TEST
    #define TEST
    class Test
    {
      friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Test&); 
    }
    #endif


    //--------Test.cpp-------------
    #include "Test.h"
    #include <iostream>

    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Test& test)
    {
      out << test;
      return out;
    }
```

Если все равно нужно подключать и в заголовочный файл, будет ли это как-то влиять на время работы программы или только на время компиляции или вообще никак не будет влиять? Почему рекомендуют не подключать много библиотек (без особых нужд)

Comment: все директивы начинающиеся на `#`, включая `#include` обрабатываются препроцессором, еще до начала компиляции. Все, что делает include так это включает в листинг программы, передаваемой компилятору содержимое файла. так что include абсолютно равнозначен написанию прямо в тексте программы его содержимого. Поэтому ответ: да, вы можете описать что угодно прямо в программе. Заголовочные файлы нужны только для удобства включения одного и того же в несколько файлов

Comment: Что касается многих бибилотек, обычно кроме включения их заголовков вы подключаете и саму бибилотеку, растет выполнимый файл, растет время запуска

Comment: @Kaznachei: Начните с того, что перестаньте называть заголовочные файлы "библиотеками". Никакого отношения ни к каким "библиотекам" ваш вопрос не имеет.

Comment: @AnT  Я имел ввиду библиотекой только `iostream`. Где я написал, что мой заголовочный файл это библиотека

Comment: @Kaznachei Именно `<iostream>` - это заголовок, а никакая не "библиотека".

Comment: @AnT Понял, прощу прощения. А как тогда назвать `#include <iostream>`

Comment: @Kaznachei Правильно - "заголовочный файл". Жаргон - "хедер", "инклюд", ...

Answer (score 2):

Для этого в заголовочном файле должно быть видно предварительное объявление `std::ostream`.

Его можно получить, заинклудив [`<iosfwd>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd) - специальный файл с предварительными объявлениями стандартных потоков. В `.cpp` файле оставьте `#include <iostream>`.

---

> Если все равно нужно подключать и в заголовочный файл, будет ли это как-то влиять на время работы программы или только на время компиляции или вообще никак не будет влиять?

Если вы добавите `#include <iostream>` в хедер, скорость компиляции может уменьшиться. Это произойдет, если ваш `test.h` включается в такие `.cpp`-файлы, которые иначе не включали бы `<iostream>` (прямо или косвенно). Потому что эффективный размер этих `.cpp`-файлов (после раскрытия всех `#include`) - возрастет.

Разницы в скорости выполнения быть не должно.

> Почему рекомендуют не подключать много библиотек (без особых нужд)

По той же причине - это замедляет компиляцию.

Comment: А можно как-то через `template` ?

Comment: @Kaznachei Не понял. Вы, конечно, можете скопировать нужные предварительные объявления из `<iosfwd>` прямо себе в код, и в них действительно используется слово `template`. Только зачем?